# selenium and XPATH unable to locate a button

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am trying to save the same stuff with selenium in my Yandex account, the problem is that when I try to pass the code to click the button "save to Yandex disk", selenium pass me the message unable to locate the element.

Thats my code:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/button[1]').click()
```

this is the page with the button "Save to yandex disk": https://yadi.sk/d/0ReZErv_cLl1-w

I read that u can also pass elements by name or by CSS selector, but when I try with firefox inspector to copy element, the browser gives me strange code.

Any suggestions?
..of course, the same error with or without logged into Yandex.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this XPath for detecting needed element:

```
//div[@class = 'folder-content content content_other content_dir']//button[contains(@class, "save")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath `//*[contains(text(),'Save to Yandex.Disk')]` to click  "Save to Yandex.Disk" button

Comment: Use relative Xpath in selenium

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that we need to improve the xpath you are using to find the element we should use the xpath that is relative but in your case you are using the xpath that is absolute, I use the extension chropath in chrome to find the xpath of the element

Below mentioned is the chro path I would recommend you to use although the above two mentioned xpath can also be used

Let me know If you have any more queries, I can form a good xpath for you

```
//div[@class='folder-content__header']//span[contains(text(),'Save to Yandex.Disk')]
```

Below mentioned is one of the xpath I have used in my own project take a look maybe this can improve your horizon

```
//label[contains(text(),'Plant Code*')]//parent::div[@class='rb_Work_FieldContainer']//following-sibling::div[contains(@class,'rb_Work_FieldValueArea rb_Work_FieldValueArea_create ')]//textarea[@class='textarea']
```